# UITableViewController custom setEditing:animated:

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am overriding the `setEditing:animated:` method in my **UITableViewController subclass** and telling it to **reload data** when the method is called.

I am using a custom UITableViewCell subclass which switched the UILabel for the title to UITextField, with initial user interaction disabled. So when the editing begins, reloading all the data will tell the cells to enable their user interaction so people can change the cell title.

> It all worked out pretty neatly except when I called

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [[self tableView] reloadData];
}
```

The editing animation gets cancelled out as if I passed NO as the "animated" argument.

Is there any work around to this?

Comment: what is happend when you call this method any error occurred ??

Comment: Try reloading the table before calling `super`'s method.

Comment: Why don't you handle the editing in the cell subclass instead of asking the table view to reload?

Comment: No there's no error, just that there's no animation. The call before super didn't work either. I'm now trying to using the cell subclass to handle the textfield delegate textFieldShouldBeginEditing: and the result is promising :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no animation because you are calling reloadData method.
Try this code:

```
       - (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated{

        NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, [self numberOfSectionsInTableView:self.tableView]);
        NSIndexSet *sections = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:range];
        [self.tableView reloadSections:sections withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];

            [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
        }
```